# Convert/ reshape a wide pandas dataframe into long/ tabular form?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, reshape, melt

I have a dataframe as below, with Dates as columns, and want to convert it into a tabular (long) form.

```
> PPPP = pd.DataFrame({'1/1/2001': [5,6,7,8,9],
>                      '1/1/2001':[45,46,47,48,49],
>                      '1/2/2001':[15,16,17,18,19],
>                      '1/3/2001':[25,26,27,28,29],
>                      'Category1':['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee'],
>                      'Category2':['XX','YY','ZZ','FF','KK']})
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to do this as it has become a nightmare for me. 
I find a lot of info on how to do the opposite with pivot (long to wide) but there does not seem to be material for the other way round. :(

Comment: Removed *"which contains Dates as columns"* from the title, because the answer is no different to any other data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df = PPPP.melt(['Category1','Category2'], value_name='a', var_name='b')
print (df)
   Category1 Category2         b   a
0         aa        XX  1/1/2001  45
1         bb        YY  1/1/2001  46
2         cc        ZZ  1/1/2001  47
3         dd        FF  1/1/2001  48
4         ee        KK  1/1/2001  49
5         aa        XX  1/2/2001  15
6         bb        YY  1/2/2001  16
7         cc        ZZ  1/2/2001  17
8         dd        FF  1/2/2001  18
9         ee        KK  1/2/2001  19
10        aa        XX  1/3/2001  25
11        bb        YY  1/3/2001  26
12        cc        ZZ  1/3/2001  27
13        dd        FF  1/3/2001  28
14        ee        KK  1/3/2001  29
```

Comment: jezrael, thank you very much for your kind response too! I really appreciate it!!

Comment: WOW!!!!!! It is so hard for me to believe there was also a one step solution!!!! BIG THANKS TO YOU TOO jezrael!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Using `stack`

```
PPPP.set_index(['Category1','Category2']).stack()
Out[226]: 
Category1  Category2          
aa         XX         1/1/2001    45
                      1/2/2001    15
                      1/3/2001    25
bb         YY         1/1/2001    46
                      1/2/2001    16
                      1/3/2001    26
cc         ZZ         1/1/2001    47
                      1/2/2001    17
                      1/3/2001    27
dd         FF         1/1/2001    48
                      1/2/2001    18
                      1/3/2001    28
ee         KK         1/1/2001    49
                      1/2/2001    19
                      1/3/2001    29
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Amazing !!!!! Following your suggestion above I tried it and combined with PPPPlong_df = PPPPstacked_df.reset_index()

Comment: Dear Wen, I don't know how to thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!...... I spent literally 3 hours (!!!!) with my head buzzing and being a python baby stepper I had hit a wall until your suggestion. MANY THANKS MAN!!!!!

Comment: @inatos yw :-) happy coding